# SQLite getColumnIndex function highlighted as error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-studio-arctic-fox

I recently upgraded Android Studio to Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2. Whenever I use this code, it is highlighted as error **(red underlines)**.

```
cursor.getColumncursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_SYNC_STATUS));
```

Screenshot of highlighted code:
[image]
This is found in all the places where the *getColumnIndex()* function is used.

**However, even if code is highlighted as an error, the compiler shows build success and the code runs fine.**

**Problem:** Due to red underlines, it is causing a bad coding experience. I would like to know if this is a bug or something is wrong with my Android Studio settings. I have tried steps like:

- Importing project again
- Invalidating caches and restart
- Deleting .idea folder to reset settings

Comment: What prompts did it display when you hover over the red error? What Is the Solution Prompt When Pressing Ctrl+Enter?

Comment: @Anna I have updated the screenshot with solution prompt. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202193843), right click and from the context actions select Suppress which will add `@SuppressLint("Range")` (easiest fix/get-around).

> I find it not feasible in my scenario to add those supresslint annotations when you have around 10-50 columns in a single table.That annotation will repeat a lot many times.

The `@Suppress("Range")` can be placed at various levels of scope you can also use Analyze/Inspect Code and edit the profile e.g.

[image]

To then find the respective code filter on the warning e.g. **Range** in this case :-

[image]

Refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

Comment: Yes ,it does work but as you said its just a get around.I find it not feasible in my scenario to add those supresslint annotations when you have around 10-50 columns in a single table.That annotation will repeat a lot many times.

Comment: @AashisShrestha as you are unaware that inspections have scope the answer has been edited to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace
`cursor.getColumncursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_SYNC_STATUS));`

as
`cursor.getColumncursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataContract.WeightEntry.COLUMN_SYNC_STATUS));`